# How to convert UTC time to local without changing hour?

Tags: javascript, react-native, momentjs

So I've seen questions like this here and on other websites, but I can't really find correct answer to my exact question. I'm using moment in my mobile react-native app and have some datepickers which gives me timestamps of chosen dates. It's usually set on chosen date on 00:00 AM but in UTC. So when I want to have the exact same hour in local time (so it's 00:00 AM but in local) I have to do this:

```
var initial = moment(date.timestamp, "x").utc();
var correct date = moment(initial.format("DD.MM.YYYY"), "DD.MM.YYYY");
```

Is there any easier way? Because all of the solutions I've seen are refering to converting UTC to local "normal way"

Comment: why not use `moment(date.timestamp).local()` to get the local time?

Comment: @AlonYampolski that will produce result which I'm not looking for. For example if you are in -8 timezone, date will change to day before, not the selected day. To check this I made 
`console.log(
      moment()
        .utc()
        .startOf("day")
        .format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm")
    ); 
//returned 27.11.2018 00:00

    console.log(
      moment(
        moment()
          .utc()
          .startOf("day")
          .format("x"),
        "x"
      )
        .local()
        .format("DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm")
    ); 
//returned 27.11.2018 01:00`